# Display inline label, input box and icon/button in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I want to display label and input on left side sequentially and button/icon on right side.
i have tried with using grid as

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-10>
        <ion-icon name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-70>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Mobile no"></ion-input>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10>
          <ion-icon name="contacts" (click)="pickContactNo()"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

It display's it inline but the input box slightly goes below.
[image: Screenshot]

also tried with item-left and item-right properties. but cant able to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon item-left name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
  <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Mobile no"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon item-right name="contacts" (click)="pickContactNo()"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

You will probably have to override some of the css in the elements of `ion-grid` otherwise.

**UPDATE** From ionic@3.4.0 :

Thanks to @keldar for the comment. According to the docs,[directional properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/rtl-support/) `item-left` and `item--right` are deprecated and you would need to use `item-start` and `item-end` which would allow to support both Right to Left and Left to Right.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon item-start name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
  <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Mobile no"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon item-end name="contacts" (click)="pickContactNo()"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Just note, as of ionic@3.4.0, the attributes `item-left` and `item-right` are now `item-start` and `item-end` respectively. :)

Comment: pickContactNo() doesn't seem to trigger. :( ionic@3.9.2

Answer (score 0):

*ion-row* has several attributes (see [Row](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/grid/Row/)). The one that looks suitable for you is *align-items-center*.
So, you can try this:

```
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row align-items-center>
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add new col, it mean that will be another column and you don't have unspecified the dimensions of these
When you add 
you can insert one ion-item to insert everything on the same line without static sizes.

```
<ion-item>
<ion-icon item-start name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Mobile no"></ion-input>
<ion-icon item-end name="contacts" (click)="pickContactNo()"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```